# Followers with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I am developing a blog using Jekyll. I've been reading over the documentation, however I realized that I haven't seen anything about followers. Does Jekyll offer an option for people to follow a blog, as well as a means to keep track of followers?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What did you call followers, github, twitter, facebook, or what else ?

Comment: I'm trying to enable followers of the blog itself. Similar to Wordpress, where someone can enter their email and follow the blog, and then they will be counted among its followers, the number of which can be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to extend the functionality of Jekyll with a custom plugin to build followers with the site. You can use social media to promote and build followers. Jekyll is just a static site/blog generator.

I would look at adding a plugin like addthis for social, etc. This will allow your users to promote content on the various social platforms.

Comment: RSS syndication could also be an option, if your target audience is into that sort of thing. An opt-in mailing list would be a good way to give updates as well. Some services offer this for free for small numbers of subscribers, one being MailChimp.

Answer (score 2):

*"Does Jekyll offer an option for people to follow a blog, as well as a means to keep track of followers?"*

The answer to that question is **NO**.

You *can* build your own plugin, but having a dynamic (user influenced) number on your website does not fit the concept of a static site (and is therefore not part of Jekyll).

A RSS feed that uses server metrics (log files) to measure the amount of readers, however, fits the Jekyll concept perfectly. A mailing list, like Brandon suggests, is also a very good solution. Adding spyware through AddThis works too, but that would be my very last resort. However, these are not solutions 'Jekyll offers'. Therefore, the answer remains 'no'.